# Bulls and Cows in Python

Tags: python, game, python-2.x

I have recently written this little [Bulls and Cows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows) game in Python:

```
"""Play Bulls and Cows."""
import random
NUM_DIGITS = 5

class IllegalNumber(Exception):
    """An exception to raise when the class Num has an instance of an
    illegal number."""
    pass

class Num(object):
    """Represent a number that consists of different NUM_DIGITS digits.
    n -- a representation of the number (int, str or a
          sequence of digits)."""
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.num = tuple(int(d) for d in str(n)) if isinstance(n, (int, str)) \
            else tuple(int(d) for d in n)  # convert n into a tuple of digits
        if not self._is_legal():
            raise IllegalNumber

    def _is_legal(self):
        if len(self.num) != NUM_DIGITS:
            return False
        if len(set(self.num)) < NUM_DIGITS: # Does it contain equal digits?
            return False
        if self.num[0] == 0:
            return False
        if not all(0 <= d <= 9 for d in self.num):
            return False
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(str(d) for d in self.num)

    def compare(self, other):
        """If one number was A's secret number and the second one
        was B's guess, how many bulls and cows are there? Return
        them in a (bulls, cows) tuple representation.

        >>> Num(1234).compare(Num(5243)) ==> 1, 2
        """
        bulls, cows = 0, 0
        for i in xrange(NUM_DIGITS):
            if self.num[i] == other.num[i]:
                bulls += 1
            elif self.num[i] in other.num:
                cows += 1
        return bulls, cows

class ComputerPlayer(object):
    """An average computer player."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.possible_nums = []
        for num in xrange(10**(NUM_DIGITS-1), 10**NUM_DIGITS):
        # Iterate over the numbers that has NUM_DIGITS digits.
            try:
                self.possible_nums.append(Num(num))
            except IllegalNumber:
                pass
        self._secret_num = random.choice(self.possible_nums)

    def guess(self, check_func):
        """Guess a number and check it with the given function.
        The function gets a guess and returns the bulls and cows.
        Return True if the player won, and False otherwise.
        """
        try:
            guess_num = random.choice(self.possible_nums)
        except IndexError:
            # If self.possible_nums is empty, the opponent cheated or
            # mistaked
            return True  # If one player mistakes, his opponent wins
        bulls, cows = check_func(guess_num)
        if bulls == NUM_DIGITS:
            return True
        self.possible_nums = [n for n in self.possible_nums
                              if n.compare(guess_num) == (bulls, cows)]
          # The possible numbers that could be the opponent's secret number.
        return self.possible_nums == []  # If it's empty, the opponent cheated

    def check(self, guess_num):
        """Check the opponent's guess, and return the bulls and cows."""
        return self._secret_num.compare(guess_num)

class HumanPlayer(object):
    """Ask the user for a guess, show him the suitable bulls and cows
    for the guess, and ask him for suitable bulls and cows for the
    opponent's guess - let the user play Bulls and Cows."""

    def guess(self, check_func):
        """Ask the user for a guess, and check it with the
        given function, that gets the guess and returns
        the bulls and cows in a (bulls, cows) representation.
        Print the results to the user.
        Return True if the player won, and False otherwise.
        """
        while True:
            try:
                guess_num = Num(raw_input('Enter a guess: '))
            except IllegalNumber:
                print ("The number should consist of %d different digits"
                       "and the first digit can't be 0." % NUM_DIGITS)
                continue
            break
        bulls, cows = check_func(guess_num)
        if (bulls, cows) == (NUM_DIGITS, 0):
            print 'You won!'
            return True
        print 'You have {} bulls and {} cows.'.format(bulls, cows)
        print '-----'
        return False

    def check(self, num):
        """Check the opponent's guess, and return the bulls and cows."""
        # The messages are indented, to improve the readibility
        # for the user - he can easily distinguish between messages
        # from `guess` and messages from `check`
        print "\tYour opponent's guess is {}.".format(num)
        bulls, cows = int(raw_input('\tBulls: ')), int(raw_input('\tCows: '))
        if (bulls, cows) == (NUM_DIGITS, 0):
            print 'You lost!'
        return bulls, cows

def play(player1, player2):
    """Play a game between the two given Player classes.
    Each player class should contain `guess` and `check` methods.
    `check` will get the opponent's guess and return the suitable
    bulls and cows, and `guess` will get a function (the opponent's
    `check` method) and let the player guess a number and check it
    with the given function. `guess` will return True if the player
    won, and False otherwise.
    Return 1 if player1 won, and 2 if player2 won.
    """
    current_player, opponent = random.sample((player1(), player2()), 2)
    while not current_player.guess(opponent.check):
        current_player, opponent = opponent, current_player
    return {player1: 1, player2: 2}[current_player.__class__]

play(HumanPlayer, ComputerPlayer)

raw_input("Thanks for playing Bulls and Cows! ")
```

It works well (as far as I know), and I want it to be reviewed. What do you think about the code?

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20338660/68063) for some more compact implementation ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`IllegalNumber`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_number) is an exception, so should be called `IllegalNumberException`. It's also not needed since `ValueError` already occupies this niche.

You should break this onto multiple lines:

```
self.num = tuple(int(d) for d in str(n)) if isinstance(n, (int, str)) \
    else tuple(int(d) for d in n)  # convert n into a tuple of digits
```

as

```
if isinstance(n, (int, str)):
    self.num = tuple(int(d) for d in str(n))
else:
    self.num = tuple(int(d) for d in n)
```

although it's simpler to do:

```
if isinstance(n, (int, str)):
    n = str(n)

self.num = tuple(map(int, n))
```

In fact, the `isinstance` check doesn't need to include `str`.

I would change `_is_legal` to

```
digits = set(range(10))

return self.num[0] and len(self.num) == NUM_DIGITS == len(digits & set(self.num))
```

I would personally use `map` in `__str__`.

`compare` can use `zip`:

```
bulls, cows = 0, 0
for digit, other_digit in zip(self.num, other.num):
    if digit == other_digit:
        bulls += 1
    elif digit in other.num:
        cows += 1
return bulls, cows
```

You could even do this:

```
pos_eq = sum(map(eq, self.num, other.num))
set_eq = len(set(self.num) & set(other.num))

return pos_eq, set_eq - pos_eq
```

although maybe I'm getting ahead of myself.

`ComputerPlayer.__init__` can generate mostly correct digits with:

```
for digits in permutations(range(10), NUM_DIGITS)
```

This gives a good speed improvement to the initial load. Since the load is still noticably slow, I suggest improving it with something like

```
    digitss = permutations(range(10), NUM_DIGITS)

    for digits in digitss:
        if digits[0]:
            break

    self.possible_nums = [digits] + map(Num, digitss)
```

and making the `_is_legal` call external so that this loop doesn't require it. I would also change the constructor to just

```
self.num = n
```

since `permutations` already returns tuples of digits. This would make `HumanPlayer.guess` start with

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input('Enter a guess: ')

    try:
        digits = map(int, inp)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        guess_num = Num(digits)
        if guess_num.is_legal():
            break

    print ("The number should consist of %d different digits "
           "and the first digit can't be 0." % NUM_DIGITS)
```

In `ComputerPlayer.guess`, you shouldn't need two checks to determine if the human cheated. Namely, the first `try...except` seems unneeded.

I like the use of a higher-order function with `check_func`. It's very elegant. However, don't abuse it; `HumanPlayer` should not be running the game; that logic should be in `play`.

It's unfortunate that you don't get an indication that you lost, or if you lost due to being caught cheating. This would be easier to sort out if more was in `play` and not in the respective classes.

You only use each method of `Num` in one place with these changes; it makes sense IMHO to make these functions on tuples of digits to remove the need to create classes. This makes things a little cleaner. It also allows one to speed up `ComputerPlayer.__init__` further.

You don't validate the user's input in `HumanPlayer.check`. `check` also shouldn't be in the business of saying `You lost!`; that should be game logic.

Using `random.sample` to shuffle in-place is fancy but it isn't good. Just use `random.shuffle` on another line.

This all gives:

```
"""Play Bulls and Cows."""
import random
NUM_DIGITS = 5

from itertools import permutations
from operator import eq

def is_legal(digits):
    return digits[0] and len(digits) == NUM_DIGITS == len(set(range(10)) & set(digits))

def format_digits(digits):
    return ''.join(map(str, digits))

def bulls_and_cows(left, right):
    """If one number was A's secret number and the second one
    was B's guess, how many bulls and cows are there? Return
    them in a (bulls, cows) tuple representation.

    >>> bulls_and_cows((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 2, 4, 3)) ==> 1, 2
    """
    pos_eq = sum(map(eq, left, right))
    set_eq = len(set(left) & set(right))

    return pos_eq, set_eq - pos_eq

def get_int(inp):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(inp))
        except ValueError:
            pass

class ComputerPlayer(object):
    """An average computer player."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.possible_nums = list(permutations(range(10), NUM_DIGITS))

        minimum = self.possible_nums.index(tuple(range(1, NUM_DIGITS+1)))
        del self.possible_nums[:minimum]

        self._secret_num = random.choice(self.possible_nums)

    def guess(self, check_func):
        """Guess a number and check it with the given function.
        The function gets a guess and returns the bulls and cows.
        Return True if the player won, and False otherwise.
        """
        guess_num = random.choice(self.possible_nums)
        bulls, cows = check_func(guess_num)

        if bulls == NUM_DIGITS:
            return True

        # The possible numbers that could be the opponent's secret number.
        self.possible_nums = [n for n in self.possible_nums if bulls_and_cows(n, guess_num) == (bulls, cows)]

        # If it's empty, the opponent cheated
        return self.possible_nums == []

    def check(self, guess_num):
        """Check the opponent's guess, and return the bulls and cows."""
        return bulls_and_cows(self._secret_num, guess_num)

class HumanPlayer(object):
    """Ask the user for a guess, show him the suitable bulls and cows
    for the guess, and ask him for suitable bulls and cows for the
    opponent's guess - let the user play Bulls and Cows."""

    def guess(self, check_func):
        """Ask the user for a guess, and check it with the
        given function, that gets the guess and returns
        the bulls and cows in a (bulls, cows) representation.
        Print the results to the user.
        Return True if the player won, and False otherwise.
        """
        while True:
            inp = raw_input('Enter a guess: ')

            try:
                guess_num = map(int, inp)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                if is_legal(guess_num):
                    break

            print ("The number should consist of %d different digits "
                   "and the first digit can't be 0." % NUM_DIGITS)

        bulls, cows = check_func(guess_num)

        if (bulls, cows) == (NUM_DIGITS, 0):
            print 'You won!'
            return True

        print 'You have {} bulls and {} cows.'.format(bulls, cows)
        print '-----'
        return False

    def check(self, num):
        """Check the opponent's guess, and return the bulls and cows."""
        # The messages are indented, to improve the readibility
        # for the user - he can easily distinguish between messages
        # from `guess` and messages from `check`
        print "\tYour opponent's guess is {}.".format(format_digits(num))
        bulls, cows = get_int('\tBulls: '), get_int('\tCows: ')

        if (bulls, cows) == (NUM_DIGITS, 0):
            print 'You lost!'

        return bulls, cows

def play(player1, player2):
    """Play a game between the two given Player classes.
    Each player class should contain `guess` and `check` methods.
    `check` will get the opponent's guess and return the suitable
    bulls and cows, and `guess` will get a function (the opponent's
    `check` method) and let the player guess a number and check it
    with the given function. `guess` will return True if the player
    won, and False otherwise.
    Return 1 if player1 won, and 2 if player2 won.
    """
    players = [player1(), player2()]
    random.shuffle(players)

    current_player, opponent = players
    while not current_player.guess(opponent.check):
        current_player, opponent = opponent, current_player

    return {player1: 1, player2: 2}[current_player.__class__]

play(HumanPlayer, ComputerPlayer)

raw_input("Thanks for playing Bulls and Cows! ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the review! However, `HumanPlayer.guess` and `HumanPlayer.check` still print `You lost!` and `You won!` in the final code - you didn't change that. I think the `play` function has to call a `HumanPlayer.end_of_game` (along with `ComputerPlayer.end_of_game`) method (with a boolean parameter for win/lose) that will print the messages - `ComputerPlayer.end_of_game` will just `pass`. What do you think?

Comment: @Avnerium "you didn't change that" → Yes, I didn't really want to make even larger changes myself. Your solution seems great: +1.

Answer (score 4):

- It look like a common behaviour you want a `Player` to have is the ability of `def check(self, num):` and `def guess(self, check_func):`. Consider adding an [ABC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) to this code `class Player` with the 2 @abstractmethods and have HumanPlayer and ComputerPlayer inherit from this.
- Move all the try and expect logic into a separate method (consider moving it in the `class Player` from the comment above if you decide to go that way), and wrap all you `raw_input` calls with this method. The idea being keep looking until you get a valid input from the user (youre' skipping this logic in `bulls, cows = int(raw_input('\tBulls: ')), int(raw_input('\tCows: '))` .. which will just crash with invalid input)

**Larger Note**
: I've been thinking the code in 5 sections (maybe reflecting hte code in these sections might make it more readable?):

1. NumberValidation: the class solely responsible for running all the `raw_input` and validating the input until we get one (no one outside of this should be calling raw_input or running validation on the input values .. the game is "stuck" at this until a valid input is recognized)
2. GameValidation: the class responsible for checking the state of the game and calling it complete once we have all bulls (a lot of the `compare` and some of the `guess` functionality can go in here)
3. Player: the [ABC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) class that represents what a player should look like with the proper default behavior
4. The `HumanPlayer` and the `ComputePlayer` class implementations
5. The main method for game play between HumanPlayer and the ComputerPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove duplicates logic in

```
self.num = tuple(int(d) for d in str(n)) if isinstance(n, (int, str)) else tuple(int(d) for d in n)
```

By writing :

```
self.num = tuple(int(d) for d in (str(n) if isinstance(n, (int, str)) else n))
```